# Remove dynamically added MovieClip using removeChild (undefined property error)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to remove a Movie Clip I created dynamically, when exporting I get the error

> 1120: Access of undefined property player_mc

```
function addplayer(id:String):MovieClip {
    var mcObj:Object=null;
    mcObj=getDefinitionByName(id.toString());
    return (new mcObj()) as MovieClip;
}
// this creates the mc
function startplayer():void {
    var player_mc:MovieClip = addplayer("s"+station.value);
    addChild(player_mc)
}
// this is supposed to remove it
function stopplayer():void {
    //the following line causes the error
    removeChild(player_mc);
}
```

As you can see I am using addChild for a Movie Clip in my library, this can be library items with the class name s1, s2, s3...

I tried using removechild(getchildbyname(?????)); with no success. how do I simply remove a Movie Clip that does not exist at export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to declare `player_mc` as a global variable and if it's **always** the last child added you may use `removeChildAt(numChildren - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare player_mc as "global variable" on top of your code and not inside the function startplayer(). Than  it should be accessible inside stoporch()

```
var player_mc:MovieClip;

function addplayer(id:String):MovieClip {
    var mcObj:Object=null;
    mcObj=getDefinitionByName(id.toString());
    return (new mcObj()) as MovieClip;
}
//this creates the mc
function startplayer():void {
    player_mc = addplayer("s"+station.value);
    addChild(player_mc)
}
//this is supposed to remove it
function stoporch():void {
    //the following line causes the error
    removeChild(player_mc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `stoporch` function is referencing a variable `player_mc` that is not in scope.  It was defined as a local in `startplayer`.

You either need to save the reference somewhere that `stoporch` can see it, or set the `name` property when you add it, and then use `getChildByName` when you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

your player_mc variable is defined locally, meaning it will disappear when the function startplayer() is done.

You can create a class variable outside of the functions:

```
private var _player_mc : MovieClip;
```

and create it like this within your function:

```
_player_mc = addplayer("s"+station.value);
```

to remove it, simply use:

```
removeChild(_player_mc);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few options exist. Like others stated, creating the variable at class level would work. Another way would be to assign a name to the clip after it is made.

```
function startplayer():void {
    player_mc = addplayer("s"+station.value);
    player_mc.name = "playerMC";
    addChild(player_mc)
    removeChild(this.getChildByName("playerMC"));
}
```